# Jenkins - how to make access to workspace restricted?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

With my default installation, workspace can be accessed by any anonymous user. I need to restrict access to authenticated users only. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jenkins go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System. In the field Access Control -> Authorization you can enable **Matrix-based security** which allows you to control which user has access to the job workspaces.

Comment: Be careful with Matrix-based security. There is an unresolved bug that just locked us out of our system. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1684